# Jhipster problem with regenerating entities

Tags: angular, spring, jhipster, code-generation

I have a problem with Jhipster. Until now, when I use in my projects command "Jhipster entity entity_name" the single entity was regenerated.
But now when I want to regenerate single entity it work for all project files. I'm using 7.2.0 version of Jhipster.
Thanks for answers.

My config:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "hello",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.2.0",
    "skipClient": false,
    "skipServer": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "blueprints": [],
    "otherModules": [],
    "pages": [],
    "creationTimestamp": 1632749058818,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "reactive": false,
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "packageName": "com.yo",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mssql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mssql",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "serverSideOptions": ["websocket:spring-websocket"],
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "withAdminUi": true,
    "clientTheme": "simplex",
    "clientThemeVariant": "primary",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "pl",
    "jwtSecretKey": "ZWE0Yzk2NjczNGU3NjJhY2VmNTg0NzdmYTVlMDA0NTE4OTVkMjhjMDRlYWQ4NTM1N2YxNjFiYTZmOTQ0MTk1MWZjNzQxZTk2NTU2NTBiYWNiMTdkYTJlYjgxZDZiODBhZWZlNDBmODQzNzM5OWQ4ZmQ3OTNlNTlkZDI5YzViY2Q=",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "languages": ["pl"],
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "lastLiquibaseTimestamp": 1632898105000,
    "entities": ["Shipment", "Localisation", "ShipmentArchive"]
  }
```

Comment: What is the error, please edit your question to paste it.

Comment: Like I said, instead of regeneration of single entity, all application entities are regenerated.

Comment: How are you regenerating your entities. Can u put the command

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to latest version? if yes and the problem still occurs, you should report it on github

Comment: @SanjeevS I use : jhipster entity Shipment